# matrices with Jordan canonical forming a two-dimensional surface

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form

I'm reading the book "Int. to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos By Stephen Wiggins" and this book find the following affirmation.

> We also show in this appendix that matrices with Jordan canonical
> form given by

$$\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\0&0 \end{matrix}\right)$$
form a two-dimensional surface.

But I don't know how prove this affirmation. Some hint? I think in the action $ Ad: GLn(\mathbb{R})^{n}\times M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})\to M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) $ given by
$$Ad(m)= gmg^{-1},$$
where $GLn(\mathbb{R})$  is  all nonsingular $n×n$
matrices, and to see that the orbit a matrix $m$ is a manifold, but I don't know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Such matrices

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}$$

have $0$ as a double eigenvalue. Therefore :

$$\operatorname{tr}(A)=\lambda_1+\lambda_2=0=a+d \tag{1}$$

and

$$\det(A)=\lambda_1\lambda_2=0=ad-bc \tag{2}$$

constituting the intersection of 3D "hypersurface" given by (2) by an hyperplane given by (1).

As a consequence, we have a surface with dimension $2$.

Said otherwise, if we plug $d=-a$ into (2) we have: $a^2=-bc$ (think to $z^2=-xy$ in our ordinary space which is the equation of a surface)

Comment: You might be interested by this general article : https://math.mit.edu/~edelman/publications/dimension_of_matrices.pdf. You will find tere explanations in terms or orbits, tangent spaces, etc. (Demmel is a renowned Numerical Analysis specialist ; he has written an excellent book on Numerical Linear Algebra)

Comment: Any comment ? ...